# How to calculate transmission delay at the application layer?

Tags: networking, internet, internet-speed, p2p, peer-to-peer

I am trying to model delay in a P2P overlay simulation and would like to clear some uncertainty with regards to the calculation of transmission delay as I haven't found any similar scenarios to mine.

I am considering only the application layer hence messages are not split according to maximum packet sizes or IP datagram sizes and no protocol overhead is assumed. Also, no interpacket or inter-message delay is considered.

Let's assume that there is a scenario where a server is serving two clients: client 1 and 2.

Server receive speed = **500 Mbps**

Server transmit speed = **100 Mbps**

Client 1 receive speed = **50 Mbps**

Client 1 transmit speed = **20 Mbps**

Client 2 receive speed = **300 Mbps**

Client 2 transmit speed = **200 Mbps**

The server needs to send 2 messages to client 1 and two other messages to client 2. All the messages are ready to be transmitted by the server.

Messages 1 and 2 to be transmitted to client 1 have sizes of **20 Mb** and **33 Mb** respectively. Messages 3 and 4 to be transmitted to client 2 have sizes of **10 Mb** and **15 Mb** respectively.

Transmission delay = Number of bits/transmission rate

a) If the server wants to send both messages to client 1 at the same time, will the number of bits be 20+33 = **53 Mb** and the transmission rate be **50 Mbps**?

b) If the server wants to send both messages to client 2 at the same time, will the number of bits be 10+15 = **25Mb** and the transmission rate be **100 Mbps**?

c) If the server wants to send messages to client 1 and client 2 at the same time, will the total transmission delay be **53/50 + 25/100-50**?

d) If the question is the same as c) but this time client 2 has a download speed of **30 Mbps**, would the total transmission delay be **53/50 + 25/30**?

For c), I wrote 100-50 because 50 Mbps are used by the server to transmit the messages to client 1 which results in the server only having 50 Mbps of available transmit speed for client 2.

Comment: I doubt this can be answered reliably with the information provided so far. It seems to me that the answer depends on how the transmission medium (media) can be shared. For example, if these devices were all on a fixed-speed medium like Gigabit Ethernet, some interleaving of packets from different messages could happen, resulting in lower transmission delay. But if these were three P2P wireless devices and their Tx/Rx speed limits are max PHY rates representing what they can do given 100% of the airtime, the answer will be different (longer delay).

Comment: The term you are looking for is probably `jitter`.

Comment: As @Spiff already pointed out this is nearly impossible to predict. bandwidth is only one factor. Others are: # hops, protocols, roundtrip time etc. Hence, there is often a big difference between theory and practice and even measurements conducted in a virtual environment often do not produce results that will reflect reality.

Comment: @Spiff first of all thanks for editing the question as it is more clear now and yes you are correct but I think you are deviating a little from the question.

It is true that the delay depends on the transmission medium but I think that is more related to propagation delay rather than transmission delay. However to address your statement, I am assuming a fixed speed medium and not considering packet interleaving.

Comment: @dirdi I agree that all of these are important. However, I believe I cannot find # of hops in the application layer as I don't have that information. Same goes for protocol, I am assuming TCP is being used but I am not considering any protocol overhead as I am dealing with the application layer. RTT is important yes, but again I think it relies more on propagation delay rather than transmission delay.

Comment: I think you guys are assuming that I am calculating the entire delay here which is not the case. I am simply trying to find the transmission delay. I am aware that the total delay constitutes of other factors such as propagation delay but that is out of the scope of this question since I am asking about transmission delay only.

Comment: @Mulishia I feel like on a fixed-speed medium you *should* be considering packet interleaving, because that's naturally going to happen on typical fixed-speed media such as wired Ethernet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume all three devices are connected to the same fixed-speed medium that exceeds any one device's maximum Tx or Rx rate. For example, a Gigabit Ethernet switch.

Your calculations for (a) and (b) look correct to me.

Unfortunately your calculation for (c) looks wrong to me. You shouldn't be adding the two terms, you should be taking the maximum of the two terms. If the server can send 100Mbps and Client 1 can only consume half of that, then the server will be sending to Client 1 at 50Mbps at the same time as it's sending to Client 2 at (the leftover) 50Mbps. Since Client 2 is only receiving 25Mbits of total data, the transmission from Server to Client 2 will be over long before the transmission from Server to Client 1 is over. So the total delay is just Client 1's 53/50.

Your item (d) contains the same logic error as (c). Once again, the transmission to Client 2 will be done before the transmission to Client 1, so the total delay is just Client 1's 53/50.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback mate.

I agree with most of what you listed but I think you meant to write 'you should be taking the maximum of the two terms' instead of minimum for c).

However I am struggling a little to understand your answers for c) and d).

For example in d), the packets to client 2 will only arrive a couple of milliseconds before client 1, should the total transmission delay still only consider client 1's delay even if the delays are close?

Comment: If the server had to send packets to 6 different clients at the same time instead of 2, then according to your answers, the transmission delay for sending packets to 6 clients could be similar or even the same as the delay for sending packets to 2 clients.

For example, maximum transmission delay out of the 6 clients the server is sending to is 53/50 and maximum transmission delay out of the 2 clients the server is sending to is also 53/50 resulting in the same transmission delays which looks really odd as I would expect longer transmission delays if more clients are being serviced.

Comment: @Mulishia Oops, right, I meant "maximum of the two terms". Fixed. As for what the "total transmission delay" entails, I think of it as being the time elapsed between when the transmitter transmits the first bit to when the transmitter transmits the final bit. In your (c) and (d) scenarios, the answer was 53/50 because all the bits that needed to go to Client 2 were transmitted in the "down times" while Client 1 was busy digesting the previous packet and not ready for the next packet (I'm talking about ~1500-Byte packets here, not your huge multi-megabit application-layer messages).

Comment: @Mulishia Adding more clients can and will add more total time, IFF the transmissions to those clients don't fit within the idle server capacity left by the transmission that takes the longest. Client 1 takes 1.06 seconds to receive 53Mbits, and leaves 53Mbits of server capacity "idle" over that 1.06 second period. Client 2 only needed about half of that idle capacity and got done in half the time. But if Client 2 had needed to receive 54Mbits, or if Client 2's max Rx rate was just 20Mbps, then it wouldn't have fit within the idle capacity during Client 1's transaction.